# Can I view Instagram Direct messages and comments programmatically?

Tags: loops, view, comments, message, instagram

I want to login in Instagram and programmatically view (iterate) through Instagram Direct messages - images and comments.

Can I do it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/) you can access images and comments but not direct messages.

Answer (score 0):

By using Private API we can view our inbox message and comment also.